# Progressive Web Apps: some precisions

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I would like to get some information about Progressive Web Apps, so here are a few questions.

1. How is a file identified as different: by comparing date/time, size, or else ?
2. What types of files are managed by PWA: only 'code' files like .html, .css and .js, or all the file types ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely up to the implementation.

[Cache.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/add) and [Cache.put()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/put) are commonly used and you you decide which requests/responses to store and when to update them.

Comment: Thanks abraham. I am running developing my app. I posted another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778169/pwa-application-issues-with-caching but got no answer unfortunately. In short this test fails: while the app is offline, I change one of the PDF files, bring back the app online and when I ask to see this PDF, I am shown the older version. I need to do a refresh for the document to change (I wish the user would not have to do anything). I tried 'Cache the network', but that does not work either.

If you look at my other question, maybe you can find what's wrong.